# Excel VBA Re-run formulas (update) when any cell in sheet changes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've written a Function in VBA to return a certain value based on certain cells' values. I execute/run this function in a formula on a certain cell

```
=MyFunction()
```

My problem is, the cells which have the above formula don't automatically update if the cells used in the function (in VBA) are changed.

How can I re-run or update or re-execute the above formula if the certain cells that are used are changed?

Comment: Excel only refreshes worksheet formulas (including UDFs) if cells in ranges which are *passed as parameters to the functions* are changed.  Excel doesn't parse your UDF source code to see if it needs to recalculate your UDF when something changes. Either pass the input ranges via your UDF's parameter list, or look at adding  `Application.Volatile` to your UDF VBA code.

Comment: Well my UDF only returns a value, it's used exactly as I stated above, not sure if this is an issue. Another issue is, it's not in the same sheet as the cells that are changing.

Comment: I edited my comment - hope that clears thing up.

Comment: It does clear some things up. My problem with `Application.Volatile` is that the cells that are changing are not in the same sheet where the function is used. All I needed to do was add a useless argument in the UDF for the range that needs to be tracked for any changed and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must recode your **UDF** to achieve the desired volatility.  Say you want the UDF to re-calculate if **A1** or **B1** or **C1** are changed, then use:

```
=MyFunction(A1,B1,C1)
```

Using *arguments* gets the required volatility.