# Macro sub calling function without any instructions

Tags: vba, excel

Please find my below VBA code.

```
Private Function NBFCYield(ByRef NOD As Variant, ByRef Total_Interest As Variant, ByRef Average_Loan As Variant)

    Yield = Total_Interest * 365
    Yield = Yield / NOD
    Yield = Yield / 100

    If Yield <> 0 Then
        NBFCYield = Yield / Average_Loan
    Else 
        NBFCYield = 0
    End If

End Function


Sub macro1()
   Cells(8, 2).ClearContents
End Sub
```

In my above Sub Macro1 I am not mentioned or call or instructed anything which use **Function NBFCYield** but still the function is triggered by Sub macro1. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have `NBFCYield` function used on the worksheet?

Comment: You are probably calling it from a worksheet_change event.  Look in the worksheet code.

Comment: Why do you think that the function is being triggered ?

Comment: @VictorK Yes I am using that function in my worksheet

Comment: @ScottCraner No sir i am not calling it from a worksheet_change event

Comment: @sagar than take a look at my answer - by changing the worksheet you trigger the function. In my answer `Application.Calculation = xlManual` turns of automatic recalculation on change. `Application.EnableEvents=False` will address `Change Event` that Scott Craner mentioned.

Comment: I think it is triggered because your Arguments are deleted (changed), as @Gary'sStudent says on [Excel VBA Re-run formulas (update) when any cell in sheet changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26267311/7690982). On macro1 you are clearing the content that your formula are getting the Arguments. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code - it should prevent triggering UDFs:

```
Sub macro1()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Cells(8, 2).ClearContents

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
end sub
```

If you are trying to determine what is calling the function you can try to use the following in the function:

```
Select Case TypeName(Application.Caller) 
Case "Range" 
v = Application.Caller.Address 
Case "String" 
v = Application.Caller
end select
msgbox v
```

Comment: I tried this as well but still NBFCYield function is triggered

Comment: no sir there is no worksheet event function i have been used. and also i have tried ur given above code for another sheet its work.. but i want to use macro code in the sheet where i have used **Function NBFCYield** also please guide the possibility...

Comment: @sagar I've added a piece of code that you have to insert into your function to see what is calling it.